# Can Pandas output inferred schema for a CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-science, data-wrangling

Is there a method I can use to output the inferred schema on a large CSV using pandas?
In addition, any way to have it tell me with that type if it is nullable/blank based off the CSV?
File is about 500k rows with 250 columns.

With my new job, I'm constantly being handed CSV files with zero format documentation.

Comment: IMO, you can read the `csv` into a `dataframe` and then do a bunch of functions. `df.shape` to tell you how many rows and columns exists. `df.isna().any()` to tell you which columns are nullable. Would need some more info to understand what you are exactly looking for.

Comment: I'd like to output the original column name with its dtype (I think). That way I can translate to systems that expect more info for each column like Microsoft SQL Server, Postgres, SQLite, or AWS Data Pipelines (Hive/Pig).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it necessary to load the whole csv file? At least you could use the read_csv function if you know the separator or doing a cat of the file to know the separator. Then use the .info():

```py
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_file,...)
df.info()
```

Comment: Can you get at this non-null count while doing a loop over the columns? What would be the idiomatic approach for this. Using Python I'd like to generate a database DDL file based on the types and nullable info. Well, at least a starting point DDL

Comment: You could do a loop using the df.columns, df.dtypes,  df['your column name'].isnull().values.any() and the f-string to create a DDL baseline.

Comment: Great ideas. Thank you